# How to add new labels to a riptable categorical?

Tags: python, python-riptable

Given this:

```
ds = rt.Dataset()
ds.my_cat = rt.Cat(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
ds.num = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

How do I do `ds.my_cat[ds.num>3] = 'd'` without it throwing an error?

Currently I de-cat the categorical to strings (slow), make my changes, and re-cat it.

Comment: Here's what I thought would work but it seems to have some problems:

ds.my_cat.category_add('d')
ds[ds.num>3, 'my_cat'] = 'd'

Comment: To be more precise: After using category_add('d') the categorical ds.my_cat has the correct categories and codes but when I display it I see "!<4>" instead of "d".